# Asynchronous (Waiting For Files)

Tags: javascript

```
function myDisplayer(some) {  
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = some; 
}
 
 function getFile(myCallback) {
   let req = new XMLHttpRequest();  
   req.open('GET', "mycar.html");
   req.onload = function() {
     if (req.status == 200) {
       myCallback(this.responseText);
     } else {
       myCallback("Error: " + req.status);
     }   
  }   
  req.send(); 
}
 
getFile(myDisplayer);
```

in this example, they're demonstrating how to wait for files. however, I really confused about this line:

```
myCallback(this.responseText);
```

why didn't they just do it like this:

```
myCallback(req.responseText);
```

[example from w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_asynchronous.asp)

Comment: Please describe your problem in more detail. What do you want to achieve? What have you tried?

Comment: don't follow w3schools. Try MDN

Comment: It seems like an idiosyncracy of the author, perhaps like a false street on a map, to see if anyone is wholesale copying the example, or scraping the page.

Comment: so does req.responseText is same as this.responseText?

Comment: don't use xhr, use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch)